# Is there a way I can use the .includes() function in JavaScript with an if () statement?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to code a tic tac toe game on repl.it. I am trying to code the `if (space owned) then` part, but I need to find out if a `p` element includes certain characters to determine if the space is owned. But when I do that, it says in the console, `TypeError: document.getElementById(...).includes is not a function
    at tac (/code.js:4:35)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (/:27:27)`
What code should I use to fix that?
The code I am using is:

```js
function tac() {
    var tac = prompt('Type the first letter of each word (e.g. If you want the top left, type tl)');
    var playerName = prompt('Are you player 1 or 2?');
    if (document.getElementById(tac).includes(' is availible')) {
        document.getElementById(tac).innerHTML = 'This space is owned by ' + playerName;
    } else {
        alert('That space is already taken!');
    }
}
```

Comment: You get that error because whatever `document.getElementById(...)` returns does not implement an `includes` function. In other word - it's not a string.

Comment: You probably meant to call `.includes()` on the `.textContent` of the element (a string), not on the element itself.

Comment: So you mean I should use `document.getElementById(...).textContent.includes();`
And does the `.includes()` function return a boolean? Like `true` or `false`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the text of the element, not the element itself.

```
if (document.getElementById(tac).innerText.includes(' is availible')) {
    document.getElementById(tac).innerText = 'This space is owned by ' + playerName;
}
```